# Abstractly How To Check If A Decryption Attempt Was Successful

Tags: c#, encryption, ascii

I have been working on the problem sets at [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) for some time and have enjoyed the challenges presented. I am currently on [Problem 59](http://projecteuler.net/problem=59) which involves the process of encryption and decryption.

The problem is, by any reasonable standard, a very simple decryption problem.

- I have been told that the encryption key consists of 3 lowercase letters.
- I have been given a description of the encryption/decryption process.
- I have been given an encrypted text file which contains only encrypted common English words

I fully understand the process of importing the data, cycling through all possible keys, and attempting to decrypt the file data with each possible key. My trouble is, after a decryption attempt with one of the keys, how can I tell if that key was the correct decryption key? As far as the computer is concerned, every decryption key just converts the data from one value to another. The meaning of that value is purely subjective/interpreted. How can I tell if a decryption key has decrypted the data into something meaningful (ie. common English words)

**Here is the code I have so far (C#):**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* Get the data from the file and convert to byte array*/
        StreamReader inData = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\thantos\Desktop\cipher1.txt");
        string[] strData = inData.ReadLine().Split(new char[] {','});
        byte[]  fileData = new byte[strData.Length];
        foreach (string x in strData) { byte.Parse(x); }

        /* for each three character lowercase password */
        for (uint i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            for (uint j = 0; j < 26; j++){
                for (uint k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
                    /* create a key */
                    byte[] key = new byte[3];
                    key[0] = (byte)(i + 97);
                    key[1] = (byte)(j + 97);
                    key[2] = (byte)(k + 97);

                    /* create temp copy of data */
                    byte[] dataCopy = new byte[fileData.Length];
                    fileData.CopyTo(dataCopy, 0);

                    /* decrypt using key */
                    for (uint l = 0; l < dataCopy.Length; l++) { 
                        dataCopy[l] = (byte)(dataCopy[l] ^ key[l%key.Length]);
                    }

                    /* cannot figure out how to check 
                     * if data is meaningfully decrypted
                     */
                    bool dataIsMeaningful = isMeaningful(dataCopy);

                    if(dataIsMeaningful) {
                      /* do stuff with data if correct 
                       * decryption key was found 
                       */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried this method for `isMeaningful()`:

```
public static isMeaningful(byte[] inData) {
  bool isGood = true;
    for (uint i = 0; good && i < inData.Length; i++) {
      isGood &= (char.IsLower((char)inData[i]));;
    }
   return isGood;
}
```

But it returns true for all 17576 possible keys.

How can I determine if the decryption key has decrypted the file data into meaningful data? I'm not looking for solution code or the answer to the Project Euler problem, I am looking for an explanation of how to check that your decryption attempt was successful.

Comment: To avoid overcomplicating, I just picked a few common English words and searched for them in the decrypted string, then stepped through the loop and tweaked my search list until it selected the only correct answer.  Cheating?  Maybe.

Comment: @SteveCzetty A very clever approach, one that I admire and will probably use to solve the problem, but it is not generalized algorithm for checking is a decryption attempt was successful that I am looking to learn (if there is one).

Comment: @SteveCzetty I thought of an even more clever solution! What is the most common character in any common English text? Search for the decryption key that gives you the most occurrences of that character. This approach gave me the answer with no tinkering, just have to know the magic character ;)

Comment: Your `isMeaningful` is broken. It should be `isGood &= (char.IsLower((char)inData[i]));`. Try that out and see if that works.

Comment: @awashburn, you're on the right track with the statistical approach.  This is how it's done in practice.  E is the most common letter in the english language.  Appearing approximately 3x more often than it would in a random choice from the 26 letters (even better if you expand that to the 256 possible bytes).  You can also look for common letter combinations, such as "th" and "he".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try different keys and score them against the letter frequency of normal English: space, followed by E, T, A, O, I, N, S, H, R, D, L, U.  Pick the highest scoring keys first for a trial.

Comment: I believe this is the best approach given so far to verify if the decryption attempt was successful; ranking each key by success probability and using human review to pick the correct key from the high probability pool.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can assume only valid ASCII values are permitted (since it should be plaintext). So for every letter you decode, just check that the resulting XOR results in a valid value: `if(dataCopy[l] < 32 ||  dataCopy[l] > 122) continue;` This should help to eliminate a vast majority of the possible key combinations.

Actually, this technique could even be used to narrow down your keyset to begin with. So instead of iterating through the loop 26^3 times over the entire 1200 character string, initially iterate 26 times and keep track of which letter at which position is still valid.

```
var letters = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Range((int)'a', 'z'-'a' + 1).Select(e => (char)e), 3).Select (e => e.ToList()).ToList();
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < passwordBytes.Length; i++)
{
    j = i % 3;
    for(int k = 0; k < letters[j].Count; k++)
    {
        byte r = (byte)(letters[j][k] ^ passwordBytes[i]);
        if(r < 32 || r > 122) letters[j].RemoveAt(k--);
    }
}
```

That should get your valid characters down to almost nothing, at which point you can just iterate over your remaining values (which shouldn't take too long) and look for a few valid sequences (I hear looking for `" the "` is a good option).

Comment: Just as a test to see how many iterations were run, the inner loop executed a total of 4434 times, meaning it averaged only 4 key iterations per letter of the encrypted string. Altogether, 5635 iterations to eliminate all but 6 possible keys from 17576.

Comment: Your approach works for the problem but is not a general method to check if your decryption attempt was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send a checksum of the original message along with the encrypted message? After decryption, compute the checksum and see if they match.

<strike>If that is not available, what about a test message? You could send a test message first such as "This is my test message" and check to see if the decrypted message matches verbatim. It's not fool-proof, but it may cover you.</strike>

Comment: I cannot send a checksum, I am given the encrypted data without a checksum. Read the full problem description [here](http://projecteuler.net/problem=59)

Comment: @awashburn I have added a second option.

Comment: Describe in more detail how the "test message" approach works. One sentence is hardly descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

When you have used a key to decrypt the data, it should have given you a text document filled with text. To check for legitimate data, would it be possible to just split the text into a text array using a space character as a delimiter, and then check each of the "words" in the array against an English dictionary?

Comment: Since my above `isMeaningful()` method returned true for all 17576 keys, that means that every possible decryption key produces a data set with no space characters because `char.IsLower(' ') == false`. I assume the original data containing English words are concatenated together without spaces.

Comment: Hmm...how about this: I'd start by checking the first two letters against a dictionary. If those two letters match up to anything else that starts with those two letters, keep on going (which it should in almost every single instance). Then check the first three letters against the dictionary, see if any words come back with the same first three letters. Keep doing this until you have the longest value you can, and once you no longer have any more matches, go back to your longest value, and if it is a complete word, return true. Should give you less answers, but take a lot longer to process.

Comment: @holeydood3, this won't work if the beginning of the second word could extend the first word. 'Looking' could be 'look' 'in' 'g...'

Comment: Valid point, but even with that, I guess they could return all strings which start with something that has a word matching at least 3 letters, and then just go through them by hand. Then hope that they didn't start the data with "a" or "is" or anything like that.

Comment: Yeah, this will trim the brute-force output.